# restrict login page access if user isLoggedin using node and express

Tags: node.js, express

login api:

```
    api.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    User.findOne({ 
        username: req.body.username
    }).select('password').exec(function(err, user) {

        if(err) throw err;

        if(!user) {
            res.send({ message: "User doesn't exist."});
        } else if(user) {

            var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);

            if(!validPassword) {
                res.send({ message: "Invalid password."});
            } else {

                /////// token

                var token = createToken(user);
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: "Successfully logged in.",
                    token: token
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

middleware:

```
api.use(function(req, res, next) {

    console.log("somebody just came to our app.");

    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // check if token exists

    if(token) {
        jsonwebtoken.verify(token, secretKey, function(err, decoded) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "failed to authenticate user."});
            } else {

                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "no token provided."});
    }
});
```

authService:

```
authFactory.login = function(username, password) {

    return $http.post('/api/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
        return data;

    })
}

authFactory.isLoggedIn = function() {
    if(AuthToken.getToken())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now, if my user is logged in and he tries to access: localhost:3000/login , then he should be redirected to localhost:3000/

only after he logs out, he should be able to access the login page (similar to facebook).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

## 1

In login API store user info in respond object(res).

## 2

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  if(req.user){
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    res.render('home');
  }
});
```

RECOMMENDED:[PASSPORT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) and its [Local-Strategy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local).

Comment: can you give me a working code for the solution? @virattara thanks in advance

Comment: Code for passport?

Comment: i am not using passport.. could you provide me a working example as i'm new to this. thanks

Comment: Sorry bro I can provide you assistance in understanding passport. I have used it but the code is quite messy, it's part of a project. Feel free to ask questions otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.loginPage = (req, res) => {
  if(req.session.user){
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    res.render("loginPage");
  }
};
```

On your **login route**, add the logic inside the middleware function. You could the same on the registration page as well.

```
exports.registrationPage = (req, res) => {
      if(req.session.user){
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        res.render("registrationPage");
    }
};
```

The key takeaway is this: **if you want a user not to see a page on your site, go to the page's route, add the if/else logic**.

Hope that helps, cheers!